# Get currently played song on Spotify

Tags: python, spotify

I'm trying to get currently played song on Spotify using Python:

```
def get_currently_played_song():
    response = requests.post(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        data={
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        },
        auth=(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID, SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET)
    )
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    current_song = requests.get(
        'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
        headers={
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
        }
    )
    print(current_song)
```

However, I'm getting a 404. I'm thinking the endpoint is wrong, but I'm not sure if I should substitute something in the URL. I tried substituting 'me' with my Spotify username, however the problem persists.

Comment: According to the docs, your endpoint is correct. An idea may be to print the `access_token` and make a request using `curl` and check the response you recieve.

Comment: @PacketLoss Hm, seems I was getting invalid username. Changed that (me) to my Spotify username, it says 'Service not found'.

Comment: You have to use `me` it is in the API documentation. If you're getting an invalid username are you sure that the 404 error is not during your authentication attempts?

Comment: Well, I can obtain the access token just fine, the 404 comes from the GET request.

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace to your question. Copy pasting your API link returns a 401 due to no token, with your token it shouldn't return a 404.

Comment: There is no stack trace, it's just a 404. `current_song.json()` prints this: `{'error': {'status': 404, 'message': 'Service not found'}}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222343/discussion-between-packetloss-and-adder).